# Push custom value to Google Maps marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to push a custom var to dynamically loaded Google Maps markers (with live user positions) {via javascript}.  In this case, I want to push a UNIX timestamp into the marker, so that way I can keep track of marker timing.  After a set interval, JS scans for markers timestamps that reach an expired time period -> then remove them.

I wanted to see if any one else played with this similar idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The good thing about the Google Maps API using Javascript is that the objects you create function just as any other object or variable you would usually find in Javascript.

This means that you can easily push a new var into the marker. I have done this myself a couple of times and it works like a charm :)

Simply go :

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
marker.timestamp = WHATEVER_YOU_WANT;
```